# Sorting Multiple Sheets With the Same Range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Trying to sort multiple sheets, used an array and unfortunately getting "Cannot set array" error. Not sure what is being done wrong here. Here is my code:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim ws() As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws() = wb.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"))
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ws.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:B6")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How many sheets are you trying to sort? How many sheets in total? You may be able to just use `For Each ws in Worksheets`

Comment: @urdearboy 3 sheets total. I have a master sheet that I do not want to sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recorded Sort syntax is way more than you actually require.

```
sub macro2()
    dim w as long, lr as long, wss as variant

    wss = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")

    for w = lbound(wss) to ubound(wss)
        with thisworkbook.worksheets(wss(w))
            lr = application.max(.cells(.rows.count, "a").end(xlup).row, _
                                 .cells(.rows.count, "b").end(xlup).row)
            with .range(.cells(1, "a"), .cells(lr, "b"))
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
            end with
        end with
    next w
end sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to an array where you should be referring to a sheet. You declared `ws` as Variant & this variable does not have properties such as `.Sort`

Notice that the array can be used as a shortcut to the sheet name, not as a shortcut to the `.Sheets("")` object.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim ws() As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
ws() = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
Dim i as Integer

For i = 0 To 2
    wb.Sheets(ws(i)).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wb.Sheets(ws(i)).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With wb.Sheets(ws(i)).Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:B6")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I find it is always a good idea to use `For i = lbound(ws) To ubound(ws)`. That way, no problem if Option Base 1 is used and it's one less thing to remember to change if you add/remove from the array.

Comment: You tackled the variant array vs worksheets object collection quite concisely. I would only be regurgitating what you pointed out and corrected so I directed my efforts to other inadequacies.